# sed: Remove everything from dot after FQDN

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I am new to `sed` and am having some troubles making it work.

What I want is this:

```
abc.ztx.com. A 132.123.12.44 ---> abc.ztx.com
```

I used the below pattern, but doesn't seem to work:

```
echo "abc.ztx.com. A 132.123.12.44" | sed 's/\.\s.+//g'
```

I verified the regex using regex101.com and pattern, `\.\s.+` matches the part `. A 132.123.12.44` perfectly. Why is it not working with `sed`.

Appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have to use `sed`? This is a perfect job for `cut`, which is what I'd use here. If you aren't stuck with sed only, let me know and I'll post a `cut` answer.

Comment: @ron-rothman Yes, please. Anything that makes the job easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sed` uses POSIX basic regular expressions (BRE) by default.  `\s` is a PCRE (Perl-compatible regular expression) which is equivalent to the BRE `[[:blank:]]` (I think, matching spaces and tabs, or possiby `[[:space:]]` which matches a larger set of whitespace characters).  The `+` is a POSIX extended regular expression (ERE) modifier, which is equivalent to `\{1,\}` as a BRE.

So try

```
sed 's/\.[[:blank:]].*//'
```

instead.  You may replace `[[:blank:]]` by a space character if you don't need to match tabs:

```
sed 's/\. .*//'
```

Note that there is no need to do the substitution with the `g` flag as there will only ever be a single match. Also, the `.+` that you use could just be replaced by `.*` instead of `.\{1,\}` as we don't care whether there are any further characters at all (just delete all of them).

Related:

- [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905)

Comment: Thank you so much Kusalananda for answering the question and also explaining the first principles of sed Regex.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Gnu/Linux, or any other Gnu, then you will have Gnu sed.
Gnu sed has the `-r` option, that allows this.

Add the option `-r` to change the dialect of regex.

e.g.

`echo "abc.ztx.com. A 132.123.12.44" | sed -r 's/\.\s.+//g'`

Comment: Wow! This is helpful too! Thank you..

Comment: While `-r` does work, `-E` is the POSIX standard switch to do this.

Comment: @DavidConrad POSIX `sed` does not support extended regular expressions nor PCREs, and does not have `-r` nor `-E` options. The `sed` used in this answer is GNU `sed`.  Most `sed` implementations supports the non-standard `-E` option to enable the use of EREs, but only GNU `sed` (AFAIK) includes the `\s` expression (along with a few other PCRE shortcuts that GNU decided to put in their regular expression library).

Comment: @Kusalananda The att sed version (from 2012-03-28) already included the  `-r` and `-E` options. Also supports the `\s`. I don't recall now if that came from super-sed or from sed 3.02.

Comment: @DavidConrad There is no accepted `-E` (yet, it may be so on future editions) in POSIX. But the idea sure came from other places, not form POSIX.

Comment: Yes, `-E` for **Extended** sounds clearer than `-r`. Both are not POSIX standard anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your question specifically asks about `sed`, but I would use `cut` for this.

If you can live with a trailing dot, then:

```
$ echo "abc.ztx.com. A 132.123.12.44" | cut -d" " -f1

abc.ztx.com.
```

If you can't live with the trailing dot, then:

```
$ echo "abc.ztx.com. A 132.123.12.44" | cut -d" " -f1 | rev | cut -d. -f2- | rev

abc.ztx.com
```

or:

```
$ echo "abc.ztx.com. A 132.123.12.44" | cut -d" " -f1 | sed -e "s/\.$//"

abc.ztx.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another possibility using `awk`, with `.` (period + space) specified as field separator:

```
echo "abc.ztx.com. A 132.123.12.44" | awk -F '\\. ' '{print $1}'

abc.ztx.com
```